# Batching and Queuing API calls in Node

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am hitting an API that takes in addresses and gives me back GPS coordinates. The API only accepts a single address, but it can handle 50 live connections at any given time. I am trying to build a function that will send 50 requests, wait until they all return and send 50 more. Or send 50 request and send the next one as a previous is returned. Below is the code I have been working with, but I am stuck.

One issue is in `batchFunct`. The `for` loop sends all the API calls, doesn’t wait for them to come back, then runs the if statement before updating `returned`. This makes since considering the asynchronicity of Node. I tried to put an `await` on the API call, but that seemingly stops all the async process (anyone have clarification on this) and effectively makes it send the requests one at a time.

Any advice on adapting this code or on finding a better way of batching and queuing API requests?

```
const array = ['address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4', '...', 'addressN']

function batchFunc(array) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var returned = 1
        for (let ele of array) {
            apiCall(ele).then(resp => { //if but an await here it will send one at a time
                console.log(resp)
                returned++
            })
        };
        if (returned == array.length) {
            resolve(returned);
        }
    })
}

async function batchCall(array) {
    while (array.length > 0) {
        let batchArray = []
        if (array.length > 50) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                batchArray.push(array[0])
                array.splice(0, 1)
            }
        } else {
            batchArray = array
            array = []
        }
        let result = await batchFunc(batchArray);
        console.log(result);
    }
}

batchCall(array)
```

Comment: Maybe [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) could help you - concurrency field.

Comment: I ended up using [async.queue](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue) which is similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [async.queue](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue), but I am still very interested in any other solutions.

```
const array = ['address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4', 'address5', 'address6']

function asyncTime(value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        apiCall(ele).then(resp => {
            resolve(resp)
        })
    })
}

function test(array) {
    var q = async.queue(async function(task, callback) {
        console.log(await asyncTime(task))
         if(callback) callback()
     }, 3);

     q.push(array, function(err) {
         if (err) {
             console.log(err)
             return
         }
         console.log('finished processing item');
     });
}
```